# JavaScript not firing in other browsers than Opera

Tags: javascript, html, .net, dom-events

I have a problem I'm battling with, I started seeing that my logs have started showing users not logging in so I started checking and noticed that the new login frame don't become visible in any other browser than Opera.

I know that the div can be visible, if I remove `display:none` the box shows as it should in all browser, so my bet is on the JavaScript not firing.

If its of any use the box I'm trying to show is a div frame as shown below but it's laying on top of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideRegLog() {
        var box = document.getElementById('LoginReg');
        if (box.style.display === 'none') {
            box.style = 'display:block; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin:-150px 0 0 -120px; z-index:99;';
        }
        else if (box.style.display === 'block') {
            box.style = 'display:none;';
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="RegFullFrame" id="LoginReg" style="display:none;">
    <div style="color:#defdef; font-size:22px; z-index:99; margin: 0 0 5px 5px; font-weight:bold;">
        Login:
    </div>
    <div class="RegTextFrame">
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="RegTextBox RegTopTexBox" ID="Usertxt" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="RegTextBox RegBottomTexBox" style="color:#989898;" ID="Pwdtxt" onfocus="this.value=''; this.type='password'; this.style.color='#000';" runat="server">
            Password
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <asp:Button CssClass="RegButton" ID="RegButton" runat="server" Text="Login" 
            onclick="Login_Click" OnClientClick="ShowHideRegLog();" />
</div>
<input id="RegButton" style=" background:none; border:none; font-weight:bold; padding-top:6px; color:red;" runat="server" 
        type="button" value="Login" onclick="ShowHideRegLog()" />
```

Comment: No change, but why whould that change anything are not === in JS the same as == in any regular language?

Comment: @AliTarhini - Why don't use `===` instead of `==`? `===` is recommeded in most case.

Comment: No, "===" means that both the value =and= the type are the same.  Many other languages only have value equivalence -- "==".

Comment: Also `==` will cause many unexpected problems like `"\n \t" == 0 //true`.

Comment: Have you done basic debugging like checking for errors in the Javascript console? If yes, have you used your browser's developer tools to check whether the function is actually called?

Comment: As far i can see in firebug when i enable on mutate no js runs, I know that js code usually runs as i checked with a similar snippet in Firefox, but not when i want a element on top of the page (im wondering if there might be a popup block of some sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jquery in `<head>` and use the following script.

```
    function ShowHideRegLog() {
        var box = document.getElementById('LoginReg');
        if (box.style.display == 'none') {
            $("#LoginReg").show();
        }
        else if (box.style.display == 'block') {
            $("#LoginReg").hide();
        }
    }
```

**Without jquery : **

```
    function ShowHideRegLog() {
        var box = document.getElementById('LoginReg');
        if (box.style.display === 'none') {
            box.style.display = 'block';
            box.style.position = 'absolute';
            box.style.top = '50%';
            box.style.margin = '-150ps 0 0 -120px';
            box.style.zIndex = '99';
        }
        else if (box.style.display === 'block') {
            box.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont want a jQuery way but a js one

Comment: take a look. i have edited the code. added without jquery option.

Comment: woa hang on there why would that work? don't get me wrong. It worked but why? only change you need to do is px instead of ps in margin, and box.style.left = '50%';

Comment: If you want to use shorthand, use `box.setAttribute('style', 'display: block; position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 99;');` to show. and `box.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');` to hide

Comment: As `<element>.style` is a attribute, you must use `<element>.setAttribute('<attribute_name>','<attribute_value>');` function to set attribute's value. You cant do it with a `=` operator. Hope you understand.